# chromedriver - Chrome failed to start: exited normally

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Does anybody know why this error is generated or where I can get more info on why is happening? The description is VERY generic and I would need to dig further to understand why this error is happening in a random way.

Start chromedriver:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(webdriverUrl)`

where webdriverUrl = path to chromedriver executable.

I'm using the chromedriver provided by node-webkit container which seems to be v2.2:
https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/chromedriver

In node-webkit you need to place chromedriver next to your container (your node-webkit).
The line above will start everything... (will execute the actual container)

The thing is.. how should I troubleshoot the error? I mean, where I can get MORE INFO about the reason why chromedriver is complaining. The error itself is VERY generic. :S

Comment: It's actually only happening on MAC

Comment: @Amey, probably in the question title.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code you are trying to use to start chromedriver?

Comment: Hi, I've just edited the original post. I'm using Python Selenium webdriver. My question is how should I troubleshoot this? Where should I look to understand why chromedriver is complaining?